# Solve $y^{\prime}+y^2-2y \sin(x) = \cos (x)-\sin^2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following DE $$y^{\prime}+y^2-2y \sin(x) = \cos (x)-\sin^2(x)$$

Clearly the DE is not separable, linear , bernoulli, exact and homogeneous. But I just learn these five types of DE. Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Its been awhile since I took diff. eq. and I hate myself for forgetting how to do this! Hopefully someone answers.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x)' = \cos(x)$ and $y^2 - 2y\sin(x) + \sin^2(x) = (y - \sin(x))^2$.

Comment: @achillehui: Thanks for your hint, now i manage to solve the DE now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the questioner has solved this particular ODE, it's time to provide some extra information.

As hinted in the comment,

$$\sin(x)' = \cos(x)\quad\text{ and }\quad y(x)^2 - 2 y(x) \sin(x) + \sin(x)^2 = (y- \sin(x))^2$$

If one define $z(x) = y(x) - \sin(x)$, the ODE can be rewritten / simplified as

$$\begin{align}
&z'(x) + z(x)^2 = 0 \\
\implies & z(x) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda\,x + 1}\\
\implies & y(x) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda\,x + 1} + \sin(x) = \frac{\lambda (1 + x\sin(x))  + \sin(x)}{\lambda\,x + 1}\tag{*1}
\end{align}$$

where $\lambda$ is some arbitrary constant. ODE of the form:

$$y'(x) = a(x) y^2(x) + b(x) y(x) + c(x)\tag{*2}$$

is called a [Ricatti equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). Its general
solution always has the form similar to $(*1)$:

$$y(x) = \frac{\lambda f_1(x) + f_2(x)}{\lambda f_3(x) + f_4(x)}$$

for arbitrary constant $\lambda$ and suitably chosen functions $f_i(x)$.

Ricatti equation has some basic properties:

1. If one solution of $(*2)$ is known, the general solution can be obtained by two quadratures (i.e. simple integration).
2. If two solutions are known, the general solution can be obtained by one 
   quadrature.
3. If three solutions $y_1, y_2, y_3$ are known, then for any other solution
   $y$ of $(*2)$, one have:
   $$\frac{y - y_1}{y - y_2} \Big/ \frac{y_3 - y_1}{y_3 - y_2} = c, \text{ a constant! }$$
   This means once you have found 3 particular solutions, you have all the solutions.

To learn this stuff, the wiki page of Ricatti equation is a possible start.
In particular, look at the section [Obtaining solutions by quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Obtaining_solutions_by_quadrature) there.